# jQuery Validate to ignore hidden fields while still validating fields hidden by a collapsed panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

First of all sorry for the long heading Working with jQuery clone + validation with my current code when the user collapse the panel when I click next button it was validating perfectly but in the panel I have one field which was hidden that should not validate when the user click next button. I have used `ignore: []` code so this was working with collapse field but not for hidden field. I want both to work when the user in collapse mode and hidden field.

Here is the jquery code

```
  $(".educationForm").validate({
        ignore:[],
         onkeyup: false,
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();

            if (errors) {
                var message = errors === 0 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
                $("#error_message").html(message);
                $(".error_msge").show();
            } else {
                $(".error_msge").hide();
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        errorPlacement: function () {
            return false;
        },
        highlight: function (element) {

            if ($(element).is(':radio'))  {

            } else {
                $(element).addClass('errRed');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');            
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {

            if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
            } else {
                $(element).removeClass('errRed');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');

        }
    });
   add_validation_for_forms();
}
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/yg97yg19/20/)

Comment: change the `ignore:[],` to `ignore:":hidden",`

Comment: I want both should happen

Comment: so the only problem is with the hidden field and you want it not to get validate when panel collapsed?

Comment: Yes correct the hidden field shouldn't validate when it's in collapse even when it us in expand but when the field are in collapse the rest of the field should get validate is that possible

Comment: which field is hidden, looked twice in the code but not able to find any field hidden

Comment: this one `<input aria-required="true" class="ipt_Field required_field txt_scr errRed" id="txt_scr" name="txt_scr" type="text">`

Comment: Text score will be the hidden field inline style for the property

Comment: @Shehary, changing `ignore:[]` to `ignore:":hidden"` will return the plugin to the default state of ignoring hidden fields.  `ignore: []` means that it will NOT ignore anything... in other words everything is validated including hidden fields.

Comment: But sparky one small when the field is in collapse mode the validate should work

Comment: For two scenario this should work one is for collapse mode and hidden field

Comment: @Sparky can you please look the above question

Comment: No, when the container is collapsed, the contents are considered "hidden" as far as this plugin is concerned.

Comment: but my problem is if i gave ignore:":hidden" this was not validating the collpase field but for me  it should validate both hidden field and collapse panel

Comment: @Sparky can you please check in my fiddle initially when the user click next button it should 5 fields but it was showing 6 fields because it was considering the hidden field

Comment: If you want to validate hidden fields, then `ignore: []` should work.  If you don't want to validate hidden fields, then remove the `ignore` option.  I think you need to put some more effort into condensing down the sample code.  Include just enough code to reproduce the problem and nothing else.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have not even told us which field is hidden.  Just put a class on this hidden field and do `ignore: ".myclass"`  It will still validate the collapsed panels but not validate the field with the `.myclass` class.  See docs:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Comment: Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate "hidden" fields (hidden by your collapsed panels) but not validate other hidden fields, then you simply need to set the `ignore` option to something much more specific.

Add a new class called `.ignore` to your hidden field(s).  Then set the `ignore` option to `".ignore"`.  Of course you can use any class or jQuery selector you wish.

```
ignore: ".ignore"
```

Now the collapsed panels will still receive validation while the hidden field is ignored.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/22/**

[See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore):

> Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. ...
>
> Example: Ignores all elements with the class "ignore" when validating.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

Comment: one more scenario i don't no whether i have to write new question or can i ask here question i have two radio button if the user select radio button this particular hidden field will be enabled that time if the user click next button this should get validate how is that possible

Comment: @Mahadevan, you can just use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to toggle `.ignore` when you enable/disable the field.  The plugin will pick it up automatically.

Comment: we have too add only class and we need to call the class in validate is this correct

Comment: @Mahadevan, simply add/remove the class when you activate/deactivate the field.  It will be validated or ignored automatically, as long as you properly set the `ignore` option as described above.

Comment: @Mahadevan, in other words, dynamically toggling the class will dynamically toggle its validation.

Comment: still i have one issue if i click the necessary radio button to show the hidden text field this was not working :(

Comment: @Mahadevan, I've fully answered the original question, and since I cannot see the code where you're going wrong, it seems this new issue of yours will require a separate question with a new MCVE:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve